# Octave leasqr error

Tags: octave

I have the following

```
x=[0.01:0.01:.1];
y=[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ];
F=@(x,p) 0.5-(1/Pi)*atan(p(2)*(x-p(1)));
p0=[0.05 10000];
```

When I run the following

```
[f p]=leasqr(x,y,p0,F)
```

I get

```
error: Invalid call to options.  Correct usage is:

 -- Function File: OPT = options ("KEY1", VALUE1, "KEY2", VALUE2, ...)

error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/help/print_usage.m at line 87, column 5
error:   /usr/share/octave/packages/control-2.3.52/options.m at line 68, column 5
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
error:   /usr/share/octave/packages/optim-1.2.0/leasqr.m at line 574, column 5
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Updated the optim package. New error message:

```
error: binary operator `.*' not implemented for `matrix' by `symbolic matrix' operations
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/packages/optim-1.2.2/private/__lm_svd__.m at line 145, column 5
error:   /usr/share/octave/packages/optim-1.2.2/leasqr.m at line 582, column 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.
According to [mail-list](https://mailman.cae.wisc.edu/pipermail/help-octave/2012-September/053970.html)

You may want to update `optim` package to fix it. The first step is system-dependent, it will install tools to compile packages, on rpm package name is different.

```
$ sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev
$ sudo octave
octave> pkg install -forge optim
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a strong suspicion... Is there a patch or new release?

Comment: Have you restarted octave after installation? I ran your code successfully

Comment: I did, is it possible I broke package dependencies with the update?

Comment: I have a lot of warnings when starting octave

Comment: I'd try to update octave. My system is Debian Wheezy/Octave 3.6.2/optim 1.2.2 (updated from forge) and everything is fine.

Comment: I am also on Debian Wheeze with octave 3.6.2 and just did the update of the optim package. No idea what happened. Thanks a lot for you help though!

Answer (score -1):

if you change "Pi" to "pi" in the function this code works for me.
except that it says "CONVERGENCE NOT ACHIEVED! "